# Whats the best way to store and sync this type of data?

Tags: mysql, storage

So basically I'm designing a web application for some users. It will allow them to store their data online and sync it between devices. I'm wondering what you guys think would be the best way to do this.

The data will essentially consist of two strings of a length of no more than 100 characters. The users would be able to create multiple lists that included multiple different string pairs, essentially like multiple different dictionaries. My initial idea was to store them in a central MySQL database using some sort of identifier for each user and set of paira, but I wonder if that might be a performance bottleneck. I'm also wondering how well a system like this would scale.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you are storing billions of such strings, use any modern storage system you want without fear of that system being a performance bottleneck.  MySQL would be fine.

Comment: How about adding a revision system into it? Such as being able to tell when it has been edited versus the client side copy? Would that add too much complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables ended up giving sufficient performance for this case use.